# JQuery Mobile Show and Hide loading message on page load

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the loading message to appear when the pages load and the is my attempt:

```
$('#page1').live("pagebeforeshow", function(e, ui){
    setTimeout($.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg, 5); 
});

$('#page1').live("pageshow", function(e, ui){
    setTimeout($.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg, 5); 
});
```

The problem with the above code is that the message is not even showing.

Is this not the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you using single-page-templates or a multi-page-template?

Comment: I'm using a single page template

Comment: Then the loading spinner should display by default when navigating between separate documents.

Comment: It's not doing it at all ... any ideas why? I am using version 1.1.1

Comment: Not off the top of my head, if you can link to a demo of the issue I can be of more help.